# How would a computer represent a negative base ten number in bits?

Tags: binary

How would a computer represent -6886707 using 24 bits?

I need someway to verify this: 100101101110101011001101.

First I converted 6886707 to binary, which is 11010010001010100110011. Then I put one zero at the left in order to have 24 bits, then I switched the zeros into ones, and ones into zeros, and added 1.

Comment: Most likely using [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). But the 24 bits might just point to this question :).

Comment: Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You didn't.  Google is ignoring the minus sign in a deceptive and unhelpful way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [2's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) way to express -6886707 using 24 bits is, acording to:

```
         100101101110101011001101 <- you
         100101101110101011001101 <- exploringbinary.com
 ‭11111111100101101110101011001101‬ <- win10 calculator in Programmer-DWORD (32 bit) mode
```

The win10 calculator agrees with you.  It just doesn't happen to have a 24 bit mode.  Chop off the extra 8 bits and you get 24 bits that match.  Those extra 1's come from something called [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension).

So you didn't do any math wrong.  Flipping the bits and adding 1 is exactly how to do two's complement negation.

Don't trust all base 10 to binary converters to do 2's complement.  [exploringbinary.com](http://www.exploringbinary.com/twos-complement-converter/) does it, as I confermed with a -1 test. -1 should give you 1's in every bit.

However, [binaryhexconverter.com](http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/decimal-to-binary-converter) doesn't and [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=-6886707%20in%20binary) doesn't.  They do positive numbers fine but don't trust them with your negatives.

Walking through the steps:

```
 Base 10   24 bits in Base 2

 6886707 = ‭011010010001010100110011  
                                    Not (flip the bits)
-6886708 = ‭100101101110101011001100
                                    Add 1
-6886707 = ‭100101101110101011001101‬
                                    Negate (change sign ±)
 6886707 = ‭011010010001010100110011
```

Add we're back where we started.  As far as I can tell your math is fine.

The lesson of 2's complement is that the two operations: `Not` and `Add 1` done in order give the same result as `Negate`.

It also works this way:

```
 Base 10   Base 2 in 24 bits

-6886707 = ‭100101101110101011001101‬
                                    Not (flip the bits)
 ‭‭6886706‬ = 011010010001010100110010‬
                                    Add 1
 6886707 = ‭011010010001010100110011‬
                                    Negate (change sign ±)
-6886707 = ‭100101101110101011001101‬
```

Said in a more functional composition way:

```
Negate(x) == AddOne(BitWiseNot(x)) is always true.
```

Which means you can use a bitwise not and addition to define negation.

Keep in mind 100101101110101011001101‬ is only equal to -6886707 when you take it as signed. When you ‭don't it's 9890509‬.

Comment: Nice answer.  To add to that, the way to represent negative numbers in binary was not always so clear. In the old early days, some used 1's complement representation.